# XML with Javascript, trying to find the name of the parent

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

I am very new to XML and am having some problems trying to get the parentnode name

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<response uri="/crm/private/xml/Contacts/getSearchRecords">
    <result>
        <Contacts>
            <row no="1">
                <FL val="CONTACTID">545094000000127015</FL>
                <FL val="First Name"><![CDATA[Roger]]></FL>
                <FL val="Last Name"><![CDATA[Rabbit]]></FL>
                <FL val="ACCOUNTID">12345678910</FL>
                <FL val="Account Name"><![CDATA[Warner Bros Inc]]></FL>
            </row>
        </Contacts>
    </result>
</response>
```

In my Javascript I can get the nodeValues of the children this way

```
parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(req.responseText, "text/xml");
//I also have the windows one but no need to see it   
var length = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("FL").length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    alert(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("FL")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}
```

I tried:

```
alert(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("FL")[i].nodeValue);
alert(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("FL")[i].childNodes[0].parentNode.nodeValue);
alert(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("FL")[i].childNodes[0].parentNode.nodeName);
```

etc. but nothing seems to work I either get Nulls or undefined. 
I basically want to get the names (First Name,ACCOUNTID,etc) so i can run a switch statement and place the node values in the appropriate locations.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

For me it's a bit unclear what you mean with "the parentNode name". Thanks to your last sentence I guess, that you'd like to get the `val` attribute of each `FL` tag?! The following should help on that:

```
alert(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("FL")[i].getAttribute('val'));
```

I recommend you to use a JavaScript console and `console.log` instead of `alert`.

Hope it helps. Have a good day.